# drupal gridview drop down menu - showing all menu and sub menus under one parent

Tags: views, 7

I would like to show drop down menus in gridview format. ideally it should show all sub menus and sub sub menues under one parrent. any module which can service this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... integrates jQuery Superfish plugin with your Drupal menus:
>
> - Unobtrusive JavaScript.
> - Keyboard-accessible, screen reader friendly.
> - Multi-column sub-menus. (Megamenus)
> - Easing effects with the jQuery Easing plug-in.
> - Automatic width calculation (sfAutomaticWidth plugin) (Use the development release)
> - Automatic sub-menu width calculation (Supersubs plugin), automatic sub-menu placement (Supposition plugin; prevents sub-menus from appearing off-screen.)
> - Touch-screen compatible. (almost)
> - Small-screen compatible. ( and vertical accordions)
> - Window width (client-side) and UA string (client-side and server-side) detection for touch and small screen plugins (no CSS3 media-queries)
> - RTL (Right-to-left) language support.
> - Plenty of built-in options for designers.
> - And a whole lot more...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the [Megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/megamenu) module is more useful. [Demo is here](http://www.aaml.org/).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Mega menus are a type of drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of the usability drawbacks to traditional style drop-downs. Primarily, mega menus have two advantages:
>
> - The information architecture of your navigation is made clearer and is visible all at once
> - The amount of clicking, searching, and navigating is reduced
>
> This module allows you to build mega menus by leveraging jQuery and the existing Drupal menu system. Megamenu takes a Drupal menu that is 3 levels deep, and converts it into a categorized 3-level mega menu, which is placed into your site as a block.